# angular forms - accessing nested controls in template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a nested control group inside my form and i want to access their form state value (like pristine and valid) to display validation errors dynamically.

The is dynamically built like this

```
controlMap['password'] = this.password;
controlMap['customData'] = this.formBuilder.group(customDataControlMap);
this.form = new FormGroup(controlMap)
```

the from obj is like

```
{
  controls:{
    password:{} 
    --->nested 
    customData:{
       controls:{
          customerId:{}
       }
    }
  }
}
```

the ngClass in the template it looks quite ugly

```
[ngClass]="( !form.controls.customData.controls.customerId.valid && !form.controls.customData.controls.customerId.touched && submitted) ? 'invalid' : ''"
```

and won't work in when i try to build it (ng build --prod)

> ERROR in
>   ng:///Users/hanche/Desktop/Development/selfbits/beratergruppe-leistungen-webclient/src/app/pages/clients/client-new/client-new.component.html
>   (6,61): Propert y 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: any plunked or html how the above hierarchy is composed? trying to achieve something similar, but the get(...) does not work as expected...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
form.get('customData').get('customerId')?.invalid
```

or

```
form.get('customData.customerId')
```

> is there a way to avoid function calls in template?

using getter

```
class YourComponent {
  get dataCustomerId() {
    return this.form.get('customData.customerId');
  }
}
```

template:

```
[ngClass]="dataCustomerId?.invalid"
```

[angular forms - accessing nested controls in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530175/angular-forms-accessing-nested-controls-in-template/43532394?noredirect=1#comment74118068_43532394)

Comment: What about `form.get('customData.customerId')`? :)

Comment: thanks that works, but is there a way to avoid function calls in template?

Comment: @HanChe you could create getter in your component